# Kotlin code "Do not place Android context classes in static fields" complaint

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android Studio based application written in Java.  I works fine
and does not cause Android Studio to complain about anything:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  static Context maincActivityContext;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainActivityContext = getApplicationContext();
    ...
  }

  /* JNI function called from c++ */
  private void updateStatus(String event, final String call) {
    ...
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
            TextView caller_uri = new TextView(mainActivityContext);
            ...
      }
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

I then went and asked Android Studio to convert it from Java
to Kotlin.  After the conversion, MainActivity looked like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mainActivityContext = applicationContext
    ...
  }

  /* JNI function called from C++ */
  private void updateStatus(String event, final String call) {
    ...
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView caller_uri = new TextView(mainActivityContext);
            ...
        }
    });
  }

  companion object {
    internal lateinit var mainActivityContext: Context
    ...
  }
}
```

Otherwise as in the Java version, but class variable mainActivityContext
was moved from the top of MainActivity to companion object.  Now again the
app worked fine, but Android Studio complained about the
mainActivityContext variable declaration:

```
Do not place Android context classes in static fields
```

I then moved the declaration back to where it was in the Java version:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  internal lateinit var mainActivityContext: Context

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    mainActivityContext = applicationContext
    ...
```

and Android Studio was satisfied.  However, when I tried to
run the app, it crashed like this:

> 03-18 16:08:52.788  7467  7467 E AndroidRuntime: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mainActivityContext has not been initialized
>
> 03-18 16:08:52.788  7467  7467 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.foo.bar.MainActivity.updateStatus(MainActivity.kt:362)

For sure the variable was (like before) initialized in onCreate function.

Question:

Why the initialization is not available in the runOnUIThread code and what is the proper way to get the variable seen as initialized there?

I checked earlier threads about this topic and could not find (or understand) an answer that would apply here.

Comment: Are you sure, your updateStatus is getting called after onCreate()?

Comment: yes, the compiler will complain about static context as it will cause memory leaks in the application. Also, you can check isInitialized for lateinit variables to make sure variable is initialized or not (kotlin 1.2)

Comment: updateStatus is called before onCreate

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that updateStatus is called after onCreate, because the C application that generates updateStatus call  is started as the last thing in onCreate (mainActitivityContext variable is set as the first thing in onCreate).

Answer (score 2):

Never put any android context inside a `static` field (which in `Kotlin` goes into the `companion object`), it is a bad practice since you can get a memory leak that way.

If you want to access the context in a class, either pass a context to it in it's constructor or if the class is like an activity, use `getApplicationContext()` to access the Context.

In your example, you don't need to store the context at all, since your activity is actually a `Context` itself (you can use `this` as context).

Comment: OP's question is why UninitializedPropertyAccessException?

Comment: this cannot be used as it's a Runnable not a Context.

Comment: It can be used. You can use `MainActivity.this` as Context.

Comment: I have tried that too.  Studio does not accept TextView(MainActivity.this).  It complains about 'this': The expression cannot be a selector.  I have also tried TextView(applicationContext) that I think in Java is TextView(getApplicationContext), and that results the same crash as before.

Comment: I now also tried that Adib suggested, i.e., TextView(this), and got a crash again.  This time `AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference` ...

Comment: I made yet another test.  This time I added statement `if (applicationContext == null)
                            Log.d("Baresip", "********* applicationContext is null")` to the front of updateStatus() function, and got crash on that line: `JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`.

Comment: To me that above means that there is no application context in a function that is called from native code and I don't understand how I could give the context as a parameter from C to Java/Kotlin.

Comment: One more comment to Adib:  I didn't put mainActivityContext variable to the companion object.  Android Studio did it when I converted a no-warnings application from Java to Kotlin.  It is not fair that Android Studio generates wrong code and then blames me about it.  If there is a proper solution, Android Studio should use it.

Comment: Juha are you sure that your Activity and Context are alive when you are calling this method? from your comments it seems that the `Context` that you are trying to get is null, and it is hinting that the object (the `Context`) that you passed is null and it cannot call `getResources()` on it.

Comment: try this, create a function inside your activity, and call it inside your `Runnable`. Inside that function call the context stuff (like `new TextView(this)`).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of mainActivityContext variable altogether by passing activity context as parameter to the function that starts the native application and then passing it back to MainActivity as parameter of updateStatus function:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        Thread(Runnable { nativeAppStart(applicationContext) }).start()
    }
}
```

Native app looks like this:

```
static jobject *appContext;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_tutpro_baresip_MainActivity_baresipStart(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject *context)
{
    appContext = context;
    ...
}
```

and its updateStatus call looks like this:

```
jmethodID statusId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, pctx->jniHelperClz,
                                         "updateStatus",
                                         "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String)V");
...
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, pctx->jniHelperObj, statusId, appContext, status);
```

Now I have working application context available in updateStatus function and th next problem is how to use that to set content view.  I'll post another question about it.

Thanks to all who contributed.

Comment: This is the follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49401122/setcontentview-crash-when-on-uithread